# a way to retrieve long text field data from ms access to matlab

Tags: matlab

when i want to get data from database (ms-access) that contains long text field  withing matlab i get this message 'Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.' 
just with the long text field included ,with other fields there is no problem
this is my code:

```
con = database.ODBCConnection('features','','');
curs = exec(con,'SELECT * FROM aa ');
setdbprefs('DataReturnFormat','cellarray');%this one with or without it 
%still the same problem
curs=fetch(curs)


   curs = 
ODBCCursor with properties:
     Data: 0
 RowLimit: 0
 SQLQuery: 'SELECT * FROM aa '
  Message: 'Invalid Cursor: Out of memory. Type HE...'
     Type: 'ODBCCursor Object'
Statement: [1x1 database.internal.ODBCStatementHandle]
```

Comment: Please only include relevant tags. This does not appear to be related to the CVT, the GUIDE or deployment. If you think they are related, [edit] the question to explain clearly how those are involved

Comment: How big is the data you're trying to fetch?

Comment: it depends from 800 to 1200 char ,it's a string with that char number that i save it from an lbp (local binary pattern ) in my face recognition application i change the result histogram of 1x256 vector into a string it gives all that huge string size i didn't find any better way to save it to database